# Automatic page break inside table cells in Latex

Tags: xslt, latex, apache-fop

I've a question about long tables in Latex.
How is it possible to automatically break text content inside a long table cell.

[image: Latex example]

I read lot of articles and examples and tried it (e.g. longtable)
But I still can not believe that there should be no solution for this. Currently I am using the Apache FOP processor to generate PDF documents via XSLT. Here, the tables are wrapped within a cell.
[Apache FOP example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AszSH.png)

Have someone the same problem and have a solution? 
Thank you, Frank